# You need to gain access to the repository before you can publish any changes. Details: Incorrect account name for the given tenant

Tags: azure, etl, devops, factory

Getting this error message "Invalid GIT configuration. You need to gain access to the repository before you can publish any changes. Details: Incorrect account name for the given tenant." while logging into Azure Data Factory. Not able to publish or save any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Check access to the Dev Ops Project connected to the Azure ADF that was setup during initial connection to the Azure DevOps Project - DEV.azure.com

Either that or change the organization name back to the original name if the URL has been updated recently.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by logging onto my Azure DevOps Project, where the Git repository for the ADF pipelines was.